# How do we configure multiple SQS consumers for same queue in Springboot application?

Tags: spring-boot, amazon-sqs, aws-sqs-fifo

I want to scale  SQS consumers in the Springboot application. Right now I am using @Sqslistner annotation to receive a message in one thread only. I want to increase SQS listeners. But I am not sure how to use @Sqslistner in multiple threads.